# How to know how much disk space a table occupies?

Tags: database, dolphindb

code as follow

```
db=database("dfs://db1",VALUE,1 2 3)
timestamp = [09:34:07,09:36:42,09:36:51,09:36:59,09:32:47,09:35:26,09:34:16,09:34:26,09:38:12]
sym = `C`MS`MS`MS`IBM`IBM`C`C`C
price= 49.6 29.46 29.52 30.02 174.97 175.23 50.76 50.32 51.29                        
qty = 2200 1900 2100 3200 6800 5400 1300 2500 8800                                
t = table(timestamp, sym, qty, price)
dt=db.createTable(t,`dt).append!(t)
```

How much disk space does this table DT consume?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getTabletsMeta function to query the disk space usage of a partition table. The code is as below, and the unit of the return value is Byte:

```py
def diskUsage(database, table){
 return select sum(diskUsage) from getTabletsMeta("/"+database+"/%", table, true, -1);
}

pnodeRun(diskUsage{"db1", "t1"})
```